# Battery/ESS cycle count, DOD

Tags: batteries

Actually, I really wonder that what is the cycle mean? How to count the cycle?
What is the real meaning of cycle life in the curve offered generally by manufacture.
[image]

Comment: Many researchers argue that the cycle means full discharge/charge cycle, but as we know, it is not always true. In the real case, so many situation that battery discharge to 50% then recharge, so how to count the cycle in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a "cycle" corresponds to 100% of the nominal capacity of the battery consumed and re-charged.

For instance, with only 10% DOD, one "cycle" would comprise 10 discharge-charge cycles of 10% each. For 50% DOD, you have two cycles of discharge and recharge which together count as one "cycle" in the specifications.

If that wasn't the case, in your example diagram, 10% DOD would only yield the energy-equivalent of 700 full cycles, compared to 500 full cycles at 100% DOD.

Comment: The energy-equivalent in your words indicates that 10% DOD would yield 7000*full capacity energy or 7000*10%(DOD)*full capacity?

Comment: I read it as 7000*full capacity, and 500*full capacity at 100% DOD.

Comment: Hmm. While failing to find the source I thought I had for my statement I have found some sources which seem to claim just the opposite.

Comment: In contrast, Apple explicitly states that one cycle equals 100% of the rated capacity, or 2x50%, ... See https://www.apple.com/batteries/why-lithium-ion/